# Using LDS without force:hasRecordId

Tags: lightning-data-service

I've seen [sfdcfox's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221617/do-you-have-to-use-the-value-returned-from-forcehasrecordid-to-use-lightning-da) to a similar question, yet am unable to replicate the result in my own component. I'd like to load a User's custom field via LDS with a User Id provided by my client controller, but am unable to successfully reload force:recordData so that it actually pulls the User's data. I'm sure it's something small, but I really can't find it and have sunk hours into this seemingly simple task. Any help is appreciated.

**component**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:handler event="c:newEngagement" action="{!c.handleNewEngagement}"/>
<!--Account Record Id-->
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
<!--Current User Record Id-->
<aura:attribute name="userId" type="Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="thisUser" type="User" default="{}"/>
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="currentUser"
                   recordId = "{!v.userId}"
                   fields="Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c, Id"
                   targetFields="{!v.thisUser}"
                   targetError="{!v.errors}"
                   mode="VIEW"/>
```

**Controller**

```
({
handleNewEngagement : function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("{!v.userId}", $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id"));
    let thisUser = component.find("currentUser");
    thisUser.reloadRecord();
    console.log(component.get("{!v.thisUser.Id}")); // returns null
    console.log(component.get("{!v.thisUser.Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c}")); // returns null
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this issue was occurring on a component being surfaced on an account detail page, I solved for this by hooking my User force:recordData reloadRecord() to an Account force:recordData recordUpdated parameter.

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:handler event="c:newEngagement" action="{!c.handleNewEngagement}"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <!--Account Record-->
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Object" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountErrors" type="String"/>
    <!--Current User Record-->
    <aura:attribute name="userId" type="Id" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="thisUser" type="Object" default="{}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errors" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="emplContactId" type="String"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="currentAccount"
                      recordId = "{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Id"
                      targetFields="{!v.account}"
                      targetError="{!v.accountErrors}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleAccountUpdated}"
                      mode="VIEW"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="currentUser"
                       recordId = "{!v.userId}"
                       fields="Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c, Id"
                       targetFields="{!v.thisUser}"
                       targetError="{!v.errors}"
                       recordUpdated="{!c.handleUserUpdated}"
                       mode="VIEW"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({

    doInit : function(component, event, helper){
        component.set("v.userId", $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id"));
    },

    handleAccountUpdated : function(component, event, helper){

        var eventParams = event.getParams();
        if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
            component.find("currentUser").reloadRecord();
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
            // record is change
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
            // record is deleted
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
            console.log('error');
            // there’s an error while loading, saving, or deleting the record
        }
    },

    handleUserUpdated : function(component, event, helper){

        var eventParams = event.getParams();
        if(eventParams.changeType === "LOADED") {
            component.set("v.emplContactId", component.get("v.thisUser.Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c"));
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
            // record is change
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "REMOVED") {
            // record is deleted
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
            console.log('error');
            // there’s an error while loading, saving, or deleting the record
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lightning Component javascript you should not use brackets and an exclamation point when referencing attributes. You JS should look something like this:

```
({
  handleNewEngagement : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.userId", $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id"));
    let thisUser = component.find("currentUser");
    thisUser.reloadRecord();
    console.log(component.get("v.thisUser.Id")); // returns null
    console.log(component.get("v.thisUser.Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c")); // returns null
})
```

EDIT1:

Also referencing the answer you attached, sfdcfox places the `reloadRecord()` action in an extra asynchronous call via `setTimeout`. Have you tried doing this as well?

EDIT2:
This is likely not the best way to do it but it might be worth a try.

```
<aura:attribute name="userId" type="Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="thisUser" type="User" default="{}"/>
<aura:attribute name="errors" type="String"/>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.userId}">
    <force:recordData aura:id="currentUser"
                   recordId = "{!v.userId}"
                   fields="Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c, Id"
                   targetFields="{!v.thisUser}"
                   targetError="{!v.errors}"
                   mode="VIEW"/>
</aura:if>
```

This way the `force:recordData` component wont load until you have filled in the userId attribute in your handler method. Also just try displaying the fields on the ui to see if they show up. Do something like:

```
Id : {!v.thisUser.Id}
Internal Emp Contact ID : {!v.thisUser.Internal_Employee_Contact_ID__c}
```

Comment: gave this a whirl, but still no luck. For what it's worth I've never had issues using bracketed references - but no brackets does look cleaner...I was thinking this had something to do with the structure of my force:recordData declaration.

Comment: @NicholasZozaya Edited

Comment: He does this because he's using returned data from a server side call to equip LDS with a record id - i'm simply attempting to reload on the client side without going to server side. So I don't think it's applicable.

Comment: It seems to be to handle `aura:valueChange` which is client side.

Comment: no dice. I even tried setting an actual timeout param of 1000 ms. nothin'

Comment: @NicholasZozaya check edit 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89703/discussion-between-nicholas-zozaya-and-zack-walton).