# Is it prudent to use force:recordData (and similar) within aura:iteration?

Tags: lightning-data-service, aura-iteration

The aura framework and lightning:recordData currently (Summer 18) support only single object retrieval.

Let's assume I got a `listItem.cmp` into which I wired `force:recordData` in `VIEW` mode or a `lightning:recordViewForm`

Is the following code, then, a good idea or a bad idea and why?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfRecordIds}" var="recordId">
    <c:listItem recordId="{recordId}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

Does the answer change if I use forms of the Lightning Data Service that also support record updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/202985) regarding `force:recordData` performance, which `lightning:recordViewForm` depends on. Basically, doing this is going to generate a ton of traffic and perform very poorly if you're dealing with more than about *six* records. So, if you expect to have only a handful of records, knock yourself out and use the `lightning:record*` elements.

However, if you expect to have a significant number of elements, you're better off writing some Apex Code to get the results back. You'll have to evaluate if the performance trade off is worth it.

Also, I might add, that a `FULL` layout, if you choose to use it, results in about 500k of data being transferred per record, which means that even if it looks okay on a desktop/laptop, mobile devices are going to chew through metered data like an unattended child does candy while Trick-or-Treating.

Comment: The `FULL` options transports Userinterface API data (Layouts, Field Info, RecType Info) - just to avoid the impression that 'full' is just bloated. I do hope we can soon access this information programmatically. I agree with your assessment that especially for iterations this is too much unnecessary data.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp Yep, it's the [ui-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/). Everything you need to render a record correctly.