# Save many records at once using "recordForm"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-record-form

How do I save many records at once by clicking the Save button?
I am not able to make the controller "handleSubmit". Please help me?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    
    <aura:attribute name="reloadForm" type="boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="listCertification" type="List" default="[1]" />
    
    <lightning:card title="Add your certifications" class="formAddCertification">
        
        <lightning:messages />
        
        <div class="buttonFormAddCert">
            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:add" variant="brand" value="Add more certification" alternativeText="Add more certification" title="Add more certification" onclick="{!c.handlerAddCert}" />
        </div>
        
        
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listCertification}" var="item">
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="{!'formAddCertification'+item}" objectApiName="Certification__c" >
                
                <div class="slds-size_6-of-6 slds-p-bottom-small">
                    <label >Developer</label>
                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="field" fieldName="Developer__c" variant="label-hidden"  required="true"/>
                </div>
                
                <div class="demo-only demo-only--sizing slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    
                    <div class="slds-size_4-of-6 slds-p-top--x-small">
                        <label >Certification</label>
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="field" fieldName="Certification__c" variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-6 slds-p-top--x-small">
                        <label >Certification Date</label>
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="field" fieldName="Certification_Date__c" variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
                
            </lightning:recordEditForm>            
        </aura:iteration>
        
        <div class="buttonForm">
            <lightning:button label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleReset}" />
            <lightning:button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.handleSubmit}"/>  
        </div>
        
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    handlerAddCert: function(component, event, helper) {
        var listCertification = component.get('v.listCertification');
        
        listCertification.push(listCertification.length+1);
        
        component.set('v.listCertification', listCertification);
    },
    
    
    handleReset: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('field').forEach(function(f) {
            f.reset();
        });
    },
    
    
    handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var listCertification = component.find('v.listCertification');
        
        
    }
    
    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

aura:id cannot be an expression, it must be a literal value.

```
aura:id="formAddCertification"
```

You can try to submit all the records at once:

```
component.find("formAddCertification")
  .forEach(function(form) {
    form.submit();
  });
```

However, this may not work well if there's a large number of records. It is strongly recommended that you use Apex to save multiple records quickly. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/202985/2984) for what you can expect with performance (it deals with loads, not saves, but the effect is similar).

Comment: After making the suggested change, I have the following error:

"
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:AddCertification$controller$handleSubmit [Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {c:AddCertification$controller$handleSubmit}
"

Could you help me again?

Comment: @Juliana make sure the aura:id matches the value used for component.find().

Comment: That was the cause of the error. Thank you.