# Update multiple record edit form records on single button click

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-controller, lightining

I have a requirement where we need to submit multiple record edit form data on single custom button click.
Below is my approach for the requirement. I need to save the record edit form data on click of submit button which is external button. Could someone please help me on this?

```
<template for:each={testData} for:item="qli">
    <lightning-record-edit-form
        key={qli.id}
        record-id={qli.Id}
        object-api-name="custom_object__c">
       
    <div class="slds-box">
      
        <lightning-output-field field-name="Name__c"></lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="test__c"></lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-output-field field-name="test12__c"></lightning-output-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="test123__c"></lightning-input-field>
    </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form><br key={qli.id}/>  
</template>

<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={submitDetails} title="OK">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Add type="submit" for button it'll implicitly will consider submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Note: You should not be using the record edit form in bulk, as it will have severe performance penalties compared to using a custom Apex method to insert/update the records ([literally over 400 times (49,000+%) slower](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/202974/2984) if more than five items are in the list).

That said, you would need to call submit on each form:

```
[...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form')].forEach(form => form.submit());
```